# Anyone know any good math equation wysiwyg's for actually letting users submit mathematical answers?

Tags: php, math, input, wysiwyg, equation

I'm setting up a little math study site and am trying to create an online practice problem system to go with it. Since most of the solutions that will be submitted are going to be pretty complex calculus equations, I need a good wysiwyg that the user can navigate efficiently and create some sort of text output that can be processed and compared with the answer on the server.

Right now I'm working with the [codecogs equation editor for fckeditor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/fckeditor/install.php) which works, more or less, but it's *really* unhandy for users, and when the user inputs something I have to pull apart the image code that it creates with a crazy regex operation to tell if it's the right answer or not.

Anyone know of anything better? I can deal with handling the unhandy return code I guess, but I really need something that's easier for the user to navigate.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433540/embeddable-wysiwyg-equation-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) has always been a tried and true solution, and is compatible with [MathJAX](https://jira.sakaiproject.org/browse/SAKIII-2341).

Comment: And how does TinyMCE handle math equations?

Comment: This is what I've decided to use. Thanks for the tip.